# Sql Query With Multiple Select Statement

Tags: mysql, sql

it's gonna be little complex.but i am trying to keep it simple.

I Want a query Where Conditions As Following

1. Users Who have `dsponserid` like My id
2. Users Who have date between `'2018-02-13' AND NEXT 7 DAYS`

*This Is Done By me. But Now where is stuck is i want If `user count` Which Passes The above Structure Is Above 5 Than Result Should Be 200 Else I Will Returns 0*

I Made This Query Which is not Working

```
SELECT
CASE 
    WHEN
        count(
            SELECT * FROM `mlm_register`
            WHERE dsponserid = 10001 
            AND `joindate` BETWEEN '2018-02-13' AND DATE_ADD('2018-02-13', INTERVAL 7 DAY)
            ) >= 5
    THEN 
        IF(
            dsponserid = 10001 
            AND `joindate` BETWEEN '2018-02-13' AND DATE_ADD('2018-02-13', INTERVAL 7 DAY), 200, 0
        )
        AS MONEY
FROM `mlm_register`
```

***Simple Explaination :***

User Count Who Passes `WHERE dsponserid = 10001 AND`joindate`BETWEEN '2018-02-13' AND DATE_ADD('2018-02-13', INTERVAL 7 DAY)` is Above  5 So  i will Return In *Output* 200 Else if User Count is below 5 So i will Returns Zero(0).

*I Hope I have Explained better.!*

Comment: Please post a schema, sample data and expected results, ideally as a SQLFiddle

Comment: @TarangP . . . I cannot imagine how that query relates to your conditions.  The query is comparing a count to "5", for instance, but that has nothing to do with the conditions.

Comment: My SQL Schema As Follow http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0b1bc8

Answer (score 1):

You can fix the syntax errors:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*)
                   FROM mlm_register r2
                   WHERE r2.dsponserid = 10001 AND
                         r2.joindate >= '2018-02-13' AND
                         r2.joindate < DATE_ADD('2018-02-13', INTERVAL 8 DAY)
                  ) < 5
             THEN 0
             WHEN r.dsponserid = 10001 AND
                  r.joindate >= '2018-02-13' AND
                  r.joindate < DATE_ADD('2018-02-13', INTERVAL 8 DAY)
             THEN 200
             ELSE 0
      END) AS MONEY
FROM mlm_register r
```

I'm not sure if this does anything useful.

Notes:

- You cannot use a subquery as the argument to `COUNT()`.
- It is best not to use `between` for dates, because of the unexpected behavior if the date is really a date/time.
- There is no need to use backticks all over the place.  That just makes the query harder to write and to read.
- I don't recommend using `IF()` because `CASE` is ANSI standard SQL.  If you do, don't mix the two types of conditional expressions.  That just makes the query harder to follow.

Comment: Good Sollution .! But `If user count Which Passes The above Structure Is Above 5 Than Result Should Be 200 Else I Will Returns 0`

Comment: @TarangP . . . I think that is what this does.  The first condition is < 5.

Answer (score 0):

As Per Answer Of **[Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff)**

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN (
                    SELECT COUNT(*)
                    FROM mlm_register r2
                    WHERE r2.dsponserid = 10001 AND
                          r2.joindate BETWEEN '2018-02-13' AND DATE_ADD('2018-02-13', INTERVAL 7 DAY)
                  ) >= 5
             THEN 200
             WHEN r.dsponserid = 10001 AND
                  r.joindate BETWEEN '2018-02-13' AND DATE_ADD('2018-02-13', INTERVAL 7 DAY)
             THEN 0
             ELSE 0
      END) AS MONEY
FROM mlm_register r
```

*And What i Required Is*

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        IF(
            (SELECT COUNT(*)
                        FROM mlm_register r2
                        WHERE r2.dsponserid = 10001 
                        AND r2.joindate BETWEEN '2018-02-13' AND DATE_ADD('2018-02-13', INTERVAL 7 DAY) ) >= 5,
            200,
            0
        )
AS TotalVal
FROM mlm_register r
```